# How to store an output value of 'X'

Tags: c, microcontroller

I am programming an µC in C, and for programming I have to use a serial connection. Using this is quite easy, I just have to store the values (e.g. `10011000`) I want to send as ints, and then convert them for sending into binary and send them one after another. But now some command bytes should look like `XXXX1001`, i.e. they contain some bits which are not set. But after the transmission size is fixed to one byte per cycle, I have to fill them up somehow. Furthermore, how can I store them? Does is simply mean that these bits are neglected, and I can set them either to `1` or to `0`?

Comment: There is no such a thing like bytes with some bits that are not "set". I's a hardware state, it can be either `0` or `1` (and please don't be picky about the tri-state, it's not the case here).

Comment: So, can I see these bits as "neglected" and therefore set them to 0 or 1?

Comment: If it is something that you read it from the datasheet, it means that these bits are just "don't care", so they do not affect the controlled device, so yes, you can set them either to `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `XXXX1001` is value for a control register to do some settings then `XXXX` means dont care here.You can set them to any value.

But beware,the same register can have different settings based on upper nibble.If so make sure you are setting them correctly.

Comment: It's good to be consistent about the way you handle `x` bit values, rather than leave them random. It's neat and tidy when debugging, and when there is a µC upgrade you can have sensible default values already in place.